# How to display a sum of TimeSpan values into a textBox as hh:mm:ss format

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm converting user-entered textBox values to TimeSpan and adding all TimeSpan values to get a "total amount of time" if you will. I then need to display that total to another textBox in hh:mm:ss format.

Right now I have it so that is adds all the values correctly, however it just returns the TotalHours value to the string instead of hh:mm:ss format.

```
    private void calculate_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TimeSpan d1 = TimeSpan.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        TimeSpan d2 = TimeSpan.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        TimeSpan d3 = TimeSpan.Parse(textBox3.Text);

        TimeSpan total = d1 + d2 + d3;

        totaltimebox.Text = (total.TotalHours).ToString();

    }
```

User enters 00:10:00 and 00:09:00.

I expect the output to be 00:19:00, but the current output is 19.

Comment: `d1` is hours, `d2` is minutes and `d3` is seconds?

Comment: `total.ToString()`?

Comment: @CodeCaster `(total.TotalHours).ToString();` should give 0. There something else to fix before using `total.ToString()` that will give `19:00:00`

Comment: @Rango I have it that way because that's the only way I know as of now. Looking for a way to display hh:mm:ss. I've tried ToString("hh:mm:ss") as well but get errors

Comment: @Cid d1 d2 and d3 are times entered by a user. So it's a running app. Some examples would be d1 = mile 1 ran in 00:09:00 d2 = mile two ran in 00:10:00.

Comment: So, the user entered **exactly** `00:09:00` in d1?

Comment: Use `DateTimePicker`s for the input, with custom format set to `HH:mm:ss` and `ShowUpDown = true`. Take the `.Value`s and sum them, then `ToString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `totaltimebox.Text= $"{total.Hours}:{total.Minutes}:{total.Seconds}";` .

It looks like what you are doing is returning the total hours, what you want to do it get the hours, minutes and seconds and singular values from the time span.

Say you had a TimeSpan of 2 days, 2 hours, 20 minutes and 10 seconds, the return value of `total.TotalHours` would = 50. Whereas you actually want the individual components (the hours, the minutes and the seconds) and so using `total.Hours` would return 2. I hope this helps.